# If you run the program in this if statement, the Y value is output as blank. How can I use syntax to get a value?

Tags: fortran

Operating System : Windows 10

Code I wrote :

```
program wire
implicit none
INTEGER :: A, B, C, Y, N, X

A = 2
B = 1
C = 3
Y = 5
N = 4
X = 2

if (A ==X) then
Read * , Y
end if

end program wire
```

When I run this program, how can I modify the code to produce a blank value when a blank appears?

Comment: I will repeat once more that Xmanager6 is NOT a Fortran compiler. It is a software that you use to connect to some remote computer. It has nothing to do with Fortran. Nothing at all. Also, I am no moderator, but I would like to make you aware that with so many downvoted questions you are coming close to a possible automatic question ban. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th  Such a ban is completely automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but is this not working?

```
program wire
implicit none
INTEGER :: A, B, C, Y, N, X

A = 2
B = 1
C = 3
Y = 5
N = 4
X = 2

if (A == X) then
    print * , Y
end if

end program wire
```

Comment: I got this error. PGF90-S-0034-Syntax error at or near = (s.f90: 12)

Comment: I edited my answer to change "=" to "==", whenever you are using an expression inside "if", it should be a comparison operation.